# Как добавить права доступа к файлу в WINDOWS10?

Tags: python, файлы, windows-10, ос, onedrive

Как из Python прочесть и изменить свойства файла.
Добавить/изменить права доступа на чтение запись удаление?
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно что-то типа `os.path.getctime(path)` но только для прав доступа к файлу?
Кроме того надо добавить доступ на запись-удаление мне как активному пользователю

История вопроса.
OneDrive залип на синхронизации файлов после переноса места хранения синхронизированных файлов на другой винт.
GOOGLE посоветовал проверить доступ. И - да!
Перебирая доступ к файлам я наткнулся на такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть файл скачался из облака, но доступа у меня к нему нет.
Файлов много искать по всем папкам вручную невозможно....
а я даже не знаю, как это спросить у GOOGLE.

**То есть я хочу пройтись по папке с подпапками, найти файлы у которых у меня нет прав на изменение и дать по ним полный доступ.** 
Но подобных свойств файла в os  и os.path не нашел.
Плохо искал?

Comment: как вариант использовать `os.system("icacls 'c:\folder\file' /q /c /t /grant Users:F")`

Comment: ну да, проще всем прописать доступ чем искать те, которым не дал…
Так и сделаю )
Без программирования ))